# Como printar o IPv6 Global usando grep e awk?

Tags: shell, awk, ipv6, grep, ipv4

Já tem alguns dias que estou pesquisando na Internet sobre tal resposta mas não obtive nenhuma até agora.
Estou tentando printar o IPv6 Global do ifconfig para ser usado em MOTD no Ubuntu.

Com o IPv4 foi bem tranquilo fazer esse processo com este comando, pois só existe um único IPv4 na inet.

```
root@gamerno:/home/stalker# ifconfig | grep 'inet' -m1 | awk {'print $2'}
192.168.254.254
```

Já para a inet6 são 3 IPv6: link local, link global e loopback.

```
root@gamerno:/home/stalker# ifconfig | grep 'inet6' | awk {'print $2'}
fe80::222:4dff:feae:31fb < link local
b00b:cafe:face:628b::dead:beef < link global
::1 < loopback
```

Lembrando que o link Global está na segunda linha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se está na segunda ou última linha, basta fazer um tail, conforme segue:

```
ifconfig | grep 'inet6' | tail -n1 | awk {'print $2'}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo o retorno, mas um amigo me deu uma luz. De tanto falar em Global que acabei usando isso para buscar o que eu queria. 
ifconfig | grep 'global' | awk {'print $2'}

Answer (score 0):

(não tenho IPv6 para testar...) mas tenta:

```
hostname -I
hostname -i
```